# Return to my app after launching safari

Tags: iphone, xcode, safari

I use this code to launch safari and post a message for the client:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.Mysite.com/testok.html"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
```

What I want to do is that after a few seconds from launching safari it would automatically close and return back to my app.

Answer (score 2):

You can register your application for a custom URL scheme and call that via Java Script from your web site. For more information on URL schemes take a look at the [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50).

Maybe a better solution would be to embed your web page into your app using an `UIWebView`.

Comment: @Sven Some time Apple reject App using UIWebview May I Know what is the Reason?

Comment: I ended up using UIWebView wich turned out to be a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Following Steps. `URLScheme` is Best Solution. I hope it is working for you.

1. In iPhone Info.plist make `URLSchemas` Like below Link

   [Client Side (iPhone Project) Setting](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)
2. Add the following Html Code to Redirect Button in Safari browser.

   ```
   <html><head>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   function redirection() {
       var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
       if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
           window.location = "myapp://"    // This is your app name. make sure it's like URLScheme Name
       }
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   Some html page
   <input type="button" value="back" onclick="redirection()"/>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```